# css crop image saving aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, crop

I have 3 columns and 3 images with different aspect ratio and resolution.
I set width: 100%; and I want to crop the bottom of each image so that each will have height: 600px;

I try this but it leads to compression or stretching of img

```
img{
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Please add a jsFiddle with an example HTML code so we could better understand your situation. It seems like the question is ambiguous.. :)

Answer (score 2):

use `height: auto`, erase the `max-width: 600px` and leave `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: then probably your images are less than 600px high in that particular situation. You don't want to stretch (= distort) them, do you?

Answer (score 2):

as an alternative solution you could define the images as background images for their containers (i.e. no `<img>` tags) and use `background-size: cover;` and `background-position: center` on them.

Comment: This won't save aspect ratio. The image will be trimmed depending on the screen resolution (it won't be distorted, but it still doesn't answer the question properly).

Comment: it *will* save the aspect ratio of the image (as opposed to width:100% and height: 100%), it will completely fill the container and cut of some parts of the picture depending on the aspect ratio of the container. Apart from that, this has nothing to do with screen resolution - the OP is talking about three columns with images in them.

Comment: `background-size: cover` is always subject to pieces of the picture cut from only one side (either the bottom or the right, if the position is the default top-left as starting point). That means the when the picture is cut, by definition it doesn't keep the aspect ratio. At least, this is how I understand it.

Comment: thank you for this comment. I think background-size: cover; will be a better idea!

Comment: @Gatto if you still want to maintain AR, and a *complete* image then use `background-size: contain;`, If you don't mind a clipped image and a little adjusting with `background-position`, then `background-size: cover` is ok.